# Reflection on swing components

Tags: java, swing, reflection

I'm trying to assign a value to a swing component through reflection. Let's use a JCheckBox for example. I have the following class:

```
public class JCheckBoxTest
{
    private JCheckBox test;

    public JCheckBoxTest()
    {
        this.test = new JCheckBox();
    }

    public reflectionTest()
    {
        Field field;
        Method method;

        field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
        method = field.getType().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelected");

        method.invoke(field, "true");
    }
}
```

This code fails at:

```
method = field.getType().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelected");
```

because it cannot find the specified "setSelected" method since it is located inside the inner class "ToggleButtonModel" of the superclass "JToggleButton" which is extended by the "JCheckBox" class.

What would be the best approach to solve this?

Thanks.

Edit: Corrected typo in code.

Comment: You could also try `Class#getMethod`, if neither of these return a `Method`, you may need to use `Class#getSuperclass` and search it and it's supper classes (until `getSuperclass` return's `null`)

Comment: Also, `setSelected` expects a `boolean` parameter, so maybe you should be using `field.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelected", boolean.class);`

Comment: Once you solved this issue, you will run into the next, as `method.invoke(field, "true")`won’t work. `setSelected` expects a `boolean` argument so you can’t pass a `String` to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Class#getMethod` and `Class#getDeclaredMethod` both provide the means to supply the name of the method and optional parameters

`JCheckBox#setSelected` requires a `boolean` paramater, so you really should be using

```
method = field.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelected", boolean.class);
```

But as you've noted, this is unlikely to work, instead, you could try

```
method = field.getClass().getMethod("setSelected", boolean.class);
```

Now, I've also had this fail to work as well, which is why I tend to use something like...

```
public static Method findMethod(Class parent, String name, Class... parameters) throws NoSuchMethodException {

    Method method = null;
    try {
        method = parent.getDeclaredMethod(name, parameters);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException exp) {
        try {
            method = parent.getMethod(name, parameters);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsm) {
            if (parent.getSuperclass() != null) {
                method = findMethod(parent.getSuperclass(), name, parameters);
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchMethodException("Could not find " + name);
            }
        }
    }
    return method;
}
```

which is a little brute force.

So with that in mind...

```
JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox();
try {
    Method method = cb.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelected", boolean.class);
    System.out.println("1. " + method);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    Method method = cb.getClass().getMethod("setSelected", boolean.class);
    System.out.println("2. " + method);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    Method method = findMethod(cb.getClass(), "setSelected", boolean.class);
    System.out.println("3. " + method);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs something like...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.swing.JCheckBox.setSelected(boolean)
2. public void javax.swing.AbstractButton.setSelected(boolean)
3. public void javax.swing.AbstractButton.setSelected(boolean)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

## Disclaimer

Reflection like this should be a last resort.  It's slow and prone to code refactoring